# Insert/Delete columns based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Screenshot]

I have no experience in Visual Basic and I am trying to add or delete columns based on a cell value while keeping the same format from the first column. I´ve seen some posts but my programming knowledge is very basic and I can´t find a way to adjust variables for it to fit into my file.

The following code seems to work for the post I read but as I said I don´t know what to change for it to work in my file:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range, ColNum As Long, TotalCol As Long, LeftFixedCol As Long
Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B1")
If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) = False Then Exit Sub
ColNum = KeyCells.Value
If ColNum <= 0 Then Exit Sub
Set Rng = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, Columns.Count))
Set c = Rng.Find("Total")     'the find is case senseticve, Change "Total" to desired key word to find
If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
TotalCol = c.Column
LeftFixedCol = 2          'Column A & B for Company and ID

Dim i As Integer
If TotalCol < LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Then ' Add column
        For i = TotalCol To LeftFixedCol + ColNum
        Columns(i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(3, i).Value = "Column " & i - LeftFixedCol ' may not use this line
        Next i
End If
If TotalCol > LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Then ' Add column
        For i = TotalCol - 1 To LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Step -1
            Columns(i).Delete
        Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Is it too much to ask if somebody could please help identifying each code line or give me a more simple code to work with?
The following gif shows exactly what I am trying to do:

[image: image2]

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: What values are you trying to change?  I would feel that the variable labels are pretty indicative, so without knowing what would need to change (as your video on imgur seems to match the minimum criteria within the code, e.g., `find` on row 3 and `B1` is your column count.

Comment: I guess another question might be where to paste this code, do I have to paste it inside the code for the sheet or do I have to insert a module for it? I tried putting it in the worksheet code I want it to work on, but it doesn´t make any changes.

Comment: This code is for a change event, specifically `Worksheet_Change`; change event code is stored within a single worksheet's module.  If the cell changed isn't `B1` within the sheet that stores said code, then nothing will occur.

Comment: I added a screenshot on my original post, could you please confirm if I am putting the code in the correct place? Once I put it there and click RUN it asks me to save the macro, but once I name and save it, another row is added for coding. Sorry if I am not understanding, but I don´t have much coding knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Insert or Delete Columns

- This code **mustn't** be copied into a standard module, e.g. `Module1` as you did.
- It **needs** to be copied into a **sheet module**, e.g. `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3` (the names not in parentheses), of the worksheet where you want this to be applied. Just double-click on the appropriate worksheet in the `Project Explorer` window (seen on the top-left of your screenshot), copy the code to the window that opens and exit the `Visual Basic Editor`.
- The code runs automatically as you change the values in the target cell (`B1` with this setup) i.e. you don't run anything.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    ' e.g. to prevent
    ' "Run-time error '1004': Microsoft Excel can't insert new cells because
    '  it would push non-empty cells off the end of the worksheet.
    '  These non-empty cells might appear empty but have blank values,
    '  some formatting, or a formula. Delete enough rows or columns
    '  to make room for what you want to insert and then try again.",
    ' which is covered for the header row, as long there is nothing
    ' to the right of the total column, but not for other rows.
   
    Const TargetCellAddress As String = "B1"
    Const TotalFirstCellAddress As String = "D3"
    Const TotalColumnTitle As String = "Total" ' case-insensitive
    
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Set TargetCell = Intersect(Me.Range(TargetCellAddress), Target)
    If TargetCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' cell not contained in 'Target'
    
    Dim NewTotalIndex As Variant: NewTotalIndex = TargetCell.Value
    
    Dim isValid As Boolean ' referring to an integer greater than 0
    
    If VarType(NewTotalIndex) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
        If Int(NewTotalIndex) = NewTotalIndex Then ' is an integer
            If NewTotalIndex > 0 Then ' is greater than 0
                isValid = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If Not isValid Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim hrrg As Range ' Header Row Range
    Dim ColumnsDifference As Long
    
    With Range(TotalFirstCellAddress)
        Set hrrg = .Resize(, Me.Columns.Count - .Column + 1)
        If NewTotalIndex > hrrg.Columns.Count Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
        ColumnsDifference = .Column - 1
    End With
    
    Dim OldTotalIndex As Variant
    OldTotalIndex = Application.Match(TotalColumnTitle, hrrg, 0)
    If IsError(OldTotalIndex) Then Exit Sub  ' total column title not found
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim hAddress As String
    
    Select Case OldTotalIndex
    Case Is > NewTotalIndex ' delete columns
        hrrg.Resize(, OldTotalIndex - NewTotalIndex).Offset(, NewTotalIndex _
            - ColumnsDifference + 2).EntireColumn.Delete xlShiftToRight
    Case Is < NewTotalIndex ' insert columns
        With hrrg.Resize(, NewTotalIndex - OldTotalIndex) _
                .Offset(, OldTotalIndex - 1)
            ' The above range becomes useless after inserting too many columns:
            hAddress = .Address
            .EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
                CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End With
        With Me.Range(hAddress)
            .Formula = "=""Column""&COLUMN()-" & ColumnsDifference - 1
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    Case Else ' is equal; do nothing
    End Select
    
SafeExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks a lot! One more question, what can I add to the code so that it keeps the formulas from the previous column? For now the format does copy but not the formulas. Could you please help me?

Comment: @ArturoC If this has resolved your question, please mark as `Answered` by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer.  Regarding your other question, please make a separate post so it can be answered, providing as much detail about the current state (e.g., where the formulae are), what you're working toward, and the steps you've taken.